# How to add an image to a cell

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

We have Word Interop based process in place to generate invoices. This process, which runs for years, loads a pre-built docx template file and populates with the data. Both header and footer of that template have a table each. Currently the code below populates the text in a given cell of the footer

```
protected override void OnEnterRow()
{
    Try(() => _parent.OLE_WordCell.Value = _parent.OLE_WordTable.Value.Cell(u.ToInt(I_RowNumber), u.ToInt(I_CellNumber)));
    Try(() => _parent.OLE_WordCell.Value.Range.Text = u.TrimEnd(I_CellText));
    Try(() => _parent.OLE_WordCell.Value.Range.Font.Bold = u.ToInt(I_CellBold));
}
```

I need to add an image to the footer of the invoice, based on a certain, simple logic. I have seen multiple examples on this and other sites how to do it. Though in my case it does add the image, but not in the footer and I will much appreciate any help.

Before doing any significant change, I wanted to simply show the image instead of the text, so I have disabled the lines above and applied the following code:

```
Try(() => _parent.OLE_WordCell.Value = _parent.OLE_WordTable.Value.Cell(u.ToInt(I_RowNumber), u.ToInt(I_CellNumber)));
Try(() => _parent.OLE_WordCell.Value.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(I_FilePath).ConvertToShape());
```

It added the image in a middle of the invoice (NOT the footer). Since I have tried various codes and below is the latest, but to no avail.

This code placed one big image all over the invoice

```
var _cell = _parent.OLE_WordTable.Value.Cell(u.ToInt(I_RowNumber), u.ToInt(I_CellNumber));
var _range = _cell.Range;
var _shape = _range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(I_FilePath.Value.ToString().Trim()).ConvertToShape();
```

so I have added height and width:

```
var _cell = _parent.OLE_WordTable.Value.Cell(u.ToInt(I_RowNumber), u.ToInt(I_CellNumber));
var _range = _cell.Range;
var _shape = _range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(I_FilePath.Value.ToString().Trim()).ConvertToShape();
_shape.HeightRelative = 8f;
_shape.WidthRelative = 10f;
```

It succeeded to reduce the size, but the image remained in a middle of the invoice. Then I have added Select() as I have seen someone advised. But that placed the image in the left top corner of the page.

```
var _cell = _parent.OLE_WordTable.Value.Cell(u.ToInt(I_RowNumber), u.ToInt(I_CellNumber));
_cell.Select();
var _range = _cell.Range;
var _shape = _range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(I_FilePath.Value.ToString().Trim()).ConvertToShape();
_shape.HeightRelative = 8f;
_shape.WidthRelative = 10f;
```

Anything else I shall try, please?

Comment: The "interop" code in the question is *not* Word's interop - something else  must be between. For that reason it's not possible to give you an answer because any code we'd provide would have to be the "raw" interop, not the API being used in the code in the question. Certainly necessary to know would be how the code is identifying the table that's apparently in the footer. The other thing to be aware of is that a `Shape` can be positioned anywhere on the page, it's not limited to a header/footer's height and width. You might check whether the **InlineShape** ends up in the cell (don't convert)

Comment: @CindyMeister I have removed convert to shape, as per your suggestion and was able to see the image in the correct place - thank you. Am now using Height and Width properties to adjust the size. Would you advise to use ScaleHeight / ScaleWidth instead? The users may have different form (square / parallelogram) of images.

Comment: If the cell has an exact cell width OR cell height the graphic should resize automatically and proportionally to that measurement, without needing to code it. Beyond that observation it's not possible to answer the question since the exact requirements are unknown to us. You need to use what works correcty when testing.